# Why $f(x)=|\sin{x}-1|=1-\sin{x}$? What if $\sin{x}-1$ is zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> $g(x)=|\sin{x}-1|+|3-\cos{x}-\sin{x}|+2\sin{x}$
>
> Answer: Above equality is simplified to $$1-\sin{x}+3-\cos{x}-\sin{x}+2\sin{x}=4-\cos{x}$$

$$-1 \le\sin{x}\le1$$

So , I know that $f(x)=|\sin{x}-1|$ will be equal to $1-\sin{x}$ when $-1 \le\sin{x}\lt1$.

But what if $\sin{x}$ is exactly $1$, then wouldn't the expression be $\sin{x}-1$?

I always considered $|x|=x$, whenever $x$ is *equal to* or greater than $0$.

Comment: If sine is exactly 1, then their difference is zero and it doesn't matter which order you write it in since either way the difference will be zero.

Comment: $$|0|=+0=-0~~$$

Comment: Yes, that's true. But in the problem I've been given, it is a crucial point since they would result in different answers. Can you please see edit?

Comment: You should have "above inequality is simplified to $1-\sin x+3-\cdots$".

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we hear that $x=|x|$ is $x$ is "positive" and $x=-|x|$ if $x$ is "negative," and often the case of $x=0$ isn't really discussed. In fact, as

$$|0|=0=-0,$$

we can include $0$ in *either* case above. In particular, we can say the following:

> If $x\leq 0$, then $|x|=-x$.

As $\sin x\leq 1$, we know $\sin x - 1 \leq 0$, so...

Comment: So does it mean that given answer is only one of two "simplifications"( we could also say $|\sin{x}-1|=\sin{x}-1$ and get $2+2\sin{x}-\cos{x}$)?

Comment: No. If you write $|\sin x - 1| = \sin x - 1$ then that is only valid if $\sin x = 1$, so your "simplification" would only be valid at those points $x$ with $\sin x = 1$.  A simplification has to be valid at all points.  $|\sin x - 1| = 1 - \sin x$ is valid at all points.

Comment: @Ted It makes sense, now. This actually answered my question, that the simplified equation has to be valid _at all points_. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$\vert \sin x - 1 \vert = \vert 1 - \sin x \vert, \; \forall x \in \Bbb R; \tag 1$

since

$1 - \sin x \ge 0,  \; \forall x \in \Bbb R, \tag 2$

$\vert \sin x - 1 \vert = \vert 1 - \sin x \vert = 1 - \sin x,  \; \forall x \in \Bbb R. \tag 3$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually, the absolute value is defined as (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Real_numbers)):
$$|x|=\begin{cases}\ \ \ x,\ x\ge 0\\ -x,\ x<0\end{cases}$$
However, it can be adjusted (see the opening paragraph in the above article):
$$|x|=\begin{cases}\ \ \ x,\ x>0\\ -x,\ x<0 \\ \ \ \ 0, \ x=0\end{cases}$$
So, using the adjusted form:
$$|\sin x-1|=\begin{cases}\ \ \ \ \sin x-1,\ \ \sin x-1>0\\ -(\sin x-1),\ \sin x-1<0 \\ \ \qquad \qquad \ 0, \ \ \sin x-1=0\end{cases} = \\ 
\begin{cases}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sin x-1,\ \  \sin x-1\not>0 \ (\emptyset)\\ \qquad \ 1-\sin x,\ \sin x-1<0 \\ \ 0=1-\sin x, \ \ \sin x-1=0\end{cases} = 1-\sin x, \sin x-1\le 0. 
$$